# Can I rely safely on OCaml's built-in order for enumerations

Tags: ocaml, enumeration

I have defined a type:

```
type day = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday
```

I know that OCaml orders automatically any type:

> ```
> val (>=) : 'a -> 'a -> bool
> ```
>
> Structural ordering functions. These functions coincide with the usual orderings over integers, characters, strings, byte sequences and floating-point numbers, and extend them to a total ordering over all types.

Therefore I can try the following:

```
# Monday < Tuesday ;;
- : bool = true
```

Can I generalize from my experimentation that any sum type will order its constructors in the order in which they were defined? Is it documented somewhere? Would it be considered bad practice if I relied on this behavior in my application?

Comment: If you want to be safe, you can add in your code you can add  ``assert ((Monday < Tuesday) && (Tuesday < Wednesday) && (Wednesday < Thursday));``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last time I looked I was a little surprised to find that the order for sum types is not documented.

The order is not the order of declaration if you have constructors that are not nullary:

```
# type abc = A | B of int | C;;
type abc = A | B of int | C
# A <  B 0;;
- : bool = true
# C < B 0;;
- : bool = true
```

You can reason out the ordering from the internal representation for sum types, but I assume it's not guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: It is not directly guaranteed to be, but it is stable and will stay like it.